# jquery validation plugin for newly created fields

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I am using jquery [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. I have an 'add file field' button which will add new file fields dynamically on click. I want to validate these fields on submit. How can I do this ? Please help..

Comment: can you add your code doing this? Normally attributes are used for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use jQuery's live or delegate methods 
http://api.jquery.com/live/
to bind the inputs created with a new validation rule.

E.g. (untested)

```
$('#addFieldButton').live('click', function() {
  $('#myFormId').append('<input type="text" id="newfield" name="newfield" />');
  $('#newfield').rules('add', {
    minlength: 2
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used the plugin, but I believe you need to apply the `.validate();` method to any elements created after document/DOM load.

```
$newFileInput=$('<input type="file" name="files[]" />');
$newFileInput.appendTo($('form[name=newFiles]')).validate();
```

Name tags used are exemplary.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new element, just after your insert it, you just add the rules then, using [`.rules('add',rules)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules), like this:

```
newField.YouJustCreatedrules("add", { required: true });
```